# Gmvault: How to skip specific mail during restore

Tags: backup, gmail

I have an issue with **restoring** a large gmail backup which I created using **Gmvault**.
Unfortunately, neither the author nor the google group of Gmvault replied to my issue, so maybe one of you guys ran into the same issue.

I try to **restore** a large Gmvault backup (80 000 mails) which worked fine for the first 50% but now **always aborts on a specific email** as shown by the ID.

I receive the following error code: **Error: Socket error [Errno: 10053]**

Before you wonder: YES, I have set "**enable_imap_compression**" to **FALSE** in the config file before even starting to restore this huge update which worked fine for the first 40 000 mails.
I am running the latest version 1.8.1.

Anybody know how to **skip this specific email when restoring** so I can restore the remaining 40 000 mails?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually relatively simple.
Remember the message ID on which the restore dies.
Then search that ID in the folder with the back up emails.
It will be a single file with the ID as a file name.
Move that file somewhere else and restore works like a charm.